# Codeigniter include file variables come null

Tags: codeigniter, load

I have a `foreach` inside a `table` that loads a file with a row `<tr>`.
That problem is that all the variables come null and I've already tried to send the variable with the load as you can see in the next code line but no success:

```
$this->load->view('pedidos/tarefas/tarefa_table', $task);
```

This is my table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Utilizador</th>
            <th>Entidade</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Data Limite</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
            foreach ($tasks as $task) { 

                $this->load->view('pedidos/tarefas/tarefa_table', $task); 

           }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the file I'm including in the load->view:
`tarefa_table.php`

```
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td><?php print_r($task->id); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo substr($task->user->name, 0, 20); if(intval(strlen($task->user->name)>=20))echo ".."; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo substr($task->entidade->name, 0, 20); if(intval(strlen($task->entidade->name)>=20))echo ".."; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo substr($task->descricao, 0, 30); if(intval(strlen($task->descricao)>=30))echo ".."; ?></td>
    <td style="<?php 
        if ($task->status_id <= 2 || $task->status_id >= 6) {
            if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($task->data_fim)) == date('Y-m-d')) {
                echo "color: orange";
            } elseif (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($task->data_fim)) < date('Y-m-d')) {
                echo "color: red";
            }else{ 
                echo "color:#274156";  
            }
        } ?>"><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($task->data_fim)) ?>
    </td>
    <td><?php 
        if($task->status_id <= 2 && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($task->data_fim)) < date('Y-m-d')){
            echo "Atraso";
        }else{
            switch ($task->status_id) {
                case 1: echo "Ativo"; break;
                case 2: echo "Atraso"; break;
                case 3: echo "Pendente"; break;
                case 4: echo "Concluído"; break;
                case 5: echo "Cancelado"; break;
                case 6: echo "Ativo"; break;
                case 7: echo "Atraso"; break;
                default: echo "Não Definido"; break;
        }}?>
    </td>
    <td class="center">                   
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'pedidos/view_task/' . $task->id ?>" title="Ver" class="tip">
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-mini"><span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-eye"></button>
        </a>             
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'pedidos/edit_task/' . $task->id ?>" title="Editar" class="tip">
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-mini"><span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-pencil-5"></button>
        </a>

        <!--<a href="<?php //echo base_url() . 'pedidos/deletetask/' . $task->id ?>" class="confirm-delete tip" title="Apagar">
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-mini"><span class="icon16 typ-icon-trashcan red"></button>
        </a>-->

    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what is the datatype of `$task` in `foreach ($tasks as $task)` line??

Comment: it's an array with data passed throw $tasks

Answer (score 0):

why not load a view in controller , loop through your data and append in your variable like
`$tablecontent`  and just echo it in your first view

```
//controller

function your_fucntion(){
$tablecontent="";
foreach ($tasks as $task) { 
$tablecontent.=$this->load->view('pedidos/tarefas/tarefa_table', $task,true); 
}
$data['tablecontent']=$tablecontent;
$this->load->view('your view path', $data);
}

 //view
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Utilizador</th>
            <th>Entidade</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Data Limite</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
         echo $tablecontent;
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't help me. Is there another way to pass $task into the external file `tarefa_table.php`?